# c# webcam focus callback

Tags: c#, .net, webcam

I was wondering if there is any library (C# .Net) to provide a callback when a focus cycle is complete like in android. Like I will do these:

1. Click a button to trigger a focus
2. Focus is complete and I get a event callback and do something in it like copying frame.

Alternatively is there anyway to know an autofocus focus has triggered and completed ?